# Problema ao retornar valor de um método

Tags: java

Estou estudando o livro da Deitel Java como programar e me deparei com um exercício que pede para fazer um reajuste salarial em 10%, a minha dúvida está no método do reajuste, meu objetivo é mostrar na tela de console o salário dos dois funcionários antes do reajuste e depois com o aumento.

Empregado:

```
public class Empregado {

    String nome, sobrenome;
    Double salarioMensal,convencao;

    public Empregado(String nomeE, String sobrenomeE, double salarioMensalE){
        if(salarioMensalE > 0.0){
            nome = nomeE;
            sobrenome = sobrenomeE;
            salarioMensal = salarioMensalE;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Salário menor que 0");
        }
    }

    //Método de reajuste salarial
    public void reajustaSalario(double valorDoReajuste){ 
        valorDoReajuste = salarioMensal+(salarioMensal*10/100); 
    } 

    public Double getConvencao() {
        return convencao;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public Double getSalarioMensal() {
        return salarioMensal;
    }

    public void setSalarioMensal(Double salarioMensal) {
        this.salarioMensal = salarioMensal;
    }
}
```

EmpregadoTeste:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmpregadoTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Empregado salario1 = new Empregado("Joao","Antonio",100.00);
        Empregado salario2 = new Empregado("Carlos","Frodo",50.00);

        System.out.printf("Empregado 1 salario: %s %s $%.2f\n",salario1.getNome(),salario1.getSobrenome(),salario1.getSalarioMensal());
        System.out.printf("Empregado 2 salario: %s %s $%.2f\n\n", salario2.getNome(),salario2.getSobrenome(),salario2.getSalarioMensal());

        //Minha dúvida procede aqui, como colocar o método do Salário reajustado?
        System.out.printf("Salario 1 atualizado: %.2f \n",        ); 
        System.out.printf("Salario 2 atualizado: %.2f ",          ); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que o seu problema reside na forma como o método `reajustaSalario` é declarado.
Sugiro que o faça desta forma:

```
public double reajustaSalario(double valorDoReajuste){ 

    return salarioMensal + (salarioMensal * valorDoReajuste/100); 

}
```

Depois pode ser utilizado da seguinte forma:

```
System.out.printf("Salario 1 atualizado: %.2f \n",salario1.reajustaSalario(10));
```

Comment: Falta um parêntese no final do segundo trecho de código.

Comment: Muito obrigado minha dúvida se encontrava em como chamar o método de reajuste, era só adicionar um return. Funcionou !!! Abraço ;)

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates Correção efetuada. obrigado.